# Как рассчитать стандартное отклонение результатов c timestamp в SQL (postgresql)?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как рассчитать стандартное отклонение результатов за последние 24 часа со стандартным отклонением результатов за последнюю неделю без последних 24 часов? (PostgreSQL)

Итак, у меня есть оператор SQL:

```
SELECT sample, AVG(countingTime) as average, STDDEV(countingTime) as stdev
FROM jmeter_results 
WHERE ttimestamp >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day') 
GROUP BY sample;
```

Но я не знаю, что должно быть в скобках после ttimestamp >= ...

Я буду очень благодарен за помощь, потому что я просто бедный студент, который не хотел работать с БД, но должен знать, как это работает.

Comment: o_O Т.е. нужно среднее за один период, а отклонение за совсем другой? И всё это в одном выходном наборе? Серьёзно? Уж лучше сделайте два отдельных запроса - и сами не запутаетесь, и других не запутаете.

Comment: Но если очень хочется - используйте отбор за неделю, а на аргумент агрегатной функции дополнительно наложите фильтр `FILTER (WHERE filter_clause)`, либо примените CASE.

Comment: @Akina Такое вот задание. Мне надо все в одном, так как я буду использовать команду для `@Query` в SpingData-JPA

Comment: Ну не вопрос, FILTER в зубы - и на баррикады.